# How do bookmarks work?

Tags: php, url, url-routing, bookmarks

Im interesting in how bookmarks work for social networks sites like facebook for example, when you look at someone's profile its

```
www.facebook.com/customname
```

or if they didnt make one yet its

```
www.facebook.com/generatedname
```

Is there a get request somewhere im missing??? Is the

```
www.facebook.com/profile.php?key=
```

hidden in the url? But how does the server know to interpret the url to look for someone's profile page? How does it work!!!!! Thanks!

Comment: The generated url has nothing to do with bookmarks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the request is usually hidden using [rewrite engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) such as [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

As such something like `facebook.com/customname` is rewritten to `facebook.com/profile.php?key=customname`, which then internally looks up the correct profile page from the database.

Answer (score 1):

There is some solution called **`mod_rewrite`**, which actually *translates* the URL visited by the user (and visible *to* the user) into the path of the script (along with all the parameters).

**Example:** when you visit eg. `http://www.facebook.com/ben`, server may actually translate it into `www.facebook.com/profile.php?name=ben` without you noticing it (because it happens on the server side).

That is how it is done.

But there is still another, loosely related solution that happens on the client side (within the user's browser, not on the server). This solution is called **`pushState`** and it is HTML5's feature (HTML5 is new standard, supporting application-like behaviours in modern browsers).

Just look at [this demonstration](http://html5demos.com/history) (it allows you to change URL, go back and forth, but if you type the visited URL directly you will show that there is nothing on the server). To make similar thing, you will need to learn JavaScript (language of the scripts executed on browser's side).

Alternatively to `pushState` some pages (like Twitter and - afair - Facebook) use solutions based on **location hash** (the part of the URL after `#`), which lets them maintain compatibility with some deprecated browsers, like IE7 etc.

Maybe this is far too much to answer your question, but you now should be pretty informed about how the URL visible to the user may differ from what is *really* invoked.

If you have any additional questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

They probably use `.htaccess` or a similar mechanism to redirect all requests to a single entry file. That file starts processing the request and can also check to see if there is an account for `customname` that was specified on the url.

Comment: Havent learn too much about .htaccess but gonna check that out now!

Comment: .htaccess is usually the file where you specify mod_rewrite rules, so if you read up about mod_rewrite, you’ll inevitably find some examples where you put those inside .htaccess ;)